# change custom Leaflet markers in html

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am beginner in development of web maps and leaflet... I found a simple but useful code for me and i want to know how to exchange all leaflet markers in the HTML code below with mylocal.png (or .svg).
Thanks in advance for any feedback !!! A good day to all

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css">
<style>
html, body, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
</style>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson/2.2.5/osmtogeojson.js"></script>
<script>
var api = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter';
var query = 'area["place"="city"]["name"="Cluj-Napoca"];node[amenity=cafe](area);out;';
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
$.get(api, {data: query}, function(resp) {
  var geojson = osmtogeojson(resp);
  var layer = L.geoJson(geojson).addTo(map);
  map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per default, when using `L.GeoJSON` every point in your GeoJSON data get turned into a default `L.Marker`. You can use the `pointToLayer` option of `L.GeoJSON` to return a customized `L.Marker` with a `L.Icon` which uses your image.

```
new L.GeoJSON(data {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return new L.Marker(latlng, {
            icon: new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
                shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',
                iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
                shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
                iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            })
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

- L.GeoJSON tutorial: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html
- Custom icon tutorial: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html

Comment: Hello iH8 , thank you for your post and for your time, what you mentioned above has a logic ... but I try to intoduce the following code in web page no longer works ... where I wrong ??? thank you in advance. I inserted the code after 'map.fitBounds (player.getBounds ()); }); '

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png', // url to your custome icon


    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
```

then put this to map initilize

```
L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
```

that's it.

Comment: That's not it, he/she isn't initializing their own markers as can be seen in the code that's posted along with the question.